# Statistical test for white noise in irregularly sampled time series in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, testing, statistics, noise

I want to test that a time series with irregular sampling is consistent with white noise.

So far, the closest function in Matlab I have found is [`lbqtest`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/econ/lbqtest.html), but this appears to only take the data as an input, rather than the times as well. Meaning that this test will only be valid for a time series with regular sampling. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Why would the distribution of white noise depend on the sampling rate?

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for dsp.stackexchange.com